# ¿Cómo puedo generar ecuaciones simultáneas de tres variables y estas solo sumen o resten el resultado?

Tags: python

Para poner en contexto intento hacer lo siguiente:

```
Es un ejercicio específico donde tengo estas tres ecuaciones:

a + b = -6
b + c = 4
a + c = 0


Si se quiere encontrar el valor de por ejemplo a, se tiene que usar dos ecuaciones, en este caso es la primera y la tercera:

a + b + a + c = -6 + 0 = -6

Luego se resta la ecuación restante que sería en este caso la segunda:

a + b + a + c - (b + c) = -6 - 4 = -10

Y se divide entre dos:
2a = -10/2 => a = -5.
```

Como se puede observar solo se restan los números, las incógnitas como `a`, `b` o `c`, no tienen ninguna función, solo se muestra de forma estética.

Ahora, explicando lo anterior, intento programarlo de la siguiente manera.

Mediante expresiones regulares creo las ecuaciones:

```
fmts = {
    '{} + {} = {}': '{}',
    '-{} + {} = {}': '-{}',  #Expresiones regulares
    '-{} - {} = {}': '{}'
}
```

Estas expresiones regulares solo pueden ser elegidas una vez por ciclo.

Mediante las variables a,b,c,d, toman la posición numérica en las expresiones regulares:

```
a,b,c,d  = [randint(0, 20) for _ in range(4)]
```

Posteriormente uso la función `random.choice()` para seleccionar aleatoriamente una de las expresiones regulares definidas en el diccionario `fmts`. La expresión seleccionada se asigna a las variables `view_expr1` y `expr1`.

Se utiliza el método `format()` para actualizar la expresión seleccionada con los valores actuales de `a`, `b`, `c` y `d`. Los valores se insertan en la expresión utilizando marcadores de posición `{}` que se reemplazarán por los valores correspondientes.
También uso el método `format()` para actualizar la expresión visual `view_expr1` con los valores actuales de `a`, `b` y el resultado de evaluar `expr1`. Se utiliza `eval(expr1)` para evaluar la expresión actualizada y obtener su resultado.

```
view_expr1, expr1 = random.choice(list(fmts.items())) #Las expresiones regulares toman la primera ecuación
expr1 = expr1.format(a, b, c, d)  # Actualizar la expresión con las variables
view_expr1 = view_expr1.format(a, b, eval(expr1))  # Evaluar la expresión
print(view_expr1)
```

Finalmente evalúo las exresiones regualres numéricas:

```
eqs = (eval(expr1) + eval(expr2) - eval(expr3)) / 2  # Evaluar la ecuación completa
```

El problema viene al ejecutar el código, porque me marca error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`, he intentado modificar las expresiones regulares y nada.

Aquí dejo el código completo:
https://pastebin.com/5kShRPgT

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar a solucuinar el problema?

De antemano, muchas gracias. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta "solve" que te hace todo esto de una forma muy fácil, no se si te vale o necesitas hacer todo el proceso.

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve

# Definir las variables
a, b, c = symbols('a b c')

# Definir las ecuaciones
eq1 = Eq(a + b, -6)
eq2 = Eq(b + c, 4)
eq3 = Eq(a + c, 0)

# Resolver el sistema de ecuaciones
sol = solve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (a, b, c))
a_value = sol[a]
b_value = sol[b]
c_value = sol[c]

# Imprimir los resultados
print("El valor de a es:", a_value)
print("El valor de b es:", b_value)
print("El valor de c es:", c_value)
```

El resultado:

```
El valor de a es: -5
El valor de b es: -1
El valor de c es: 5
```

## Edito:

He modificado tu código para que sea funcional pero no se si tiene el resultado que deseas:

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, sympify
import random

archivo = open('Ejercicio5.6.1.txt', 'w')  # Abre el archivo en modo escritura
result = []

equations = []

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'  # Alfabeto fijo

for i in range(1000):
    variables = symbols(random.sample(alphabet, 4))  # Seleccionar 4 letras aleatoriamente
    a, b, c, d = variables

    expr1 = '{} + {} = {}'.format(a, b, random.choice([c, d]))  # Genera la primera expresión aleatoria
    view_expr1 = '{} + {} = {}'.format(a, b, expr1.split('=')[1])  # Crea la versión imprimible de la expresión

    expr2 = '-{} + {} = {}'.format(a, b, random.choice([c, d]))  # Genera la segunda expresión aleatoria
    view_expr2 = '-{} + {} = {}'.format(a, b, expr2.split('=')[1])  # Crea la versión imprimible de la expresión

    expr3 = '-{} - {} = {}'.format(a, b, random.choice([c, d]))  # Genera la tercera expresión aleatoria
    view_expr3 = '-{} - {} = {}'.format(a, b, expr3.split('=')[1])  # Crea la versión imprimible de la expresión

    eq = (view_expr1, view_expr2, view_expr3)
    if eq in equations:
        continue

    equations.append(eq)

    eqs = Eq(sympify(view_expr1.split('=')[0].strip()), sympify(view_expr1.split('=')[1].strip()))  # Crea la ecuación con sympy

    resultado = solve(eqs)  # Resuelve la ecuación
    if resultado not in result:
        result.append(resultado)

        archivo.write(f'{view_expr1}\n{view_expr2}\n{view_expr3}\n\n')  # Escribe las expresiones en el archivo

archivo.write('\n\n-----------------------------------------------\n\n')

for i in range(len(result)):
    archivo.write(f'{result[i]}\n')  # Escribe los resultados en el archivo

archivo.close()  # Cierra el archivo
```

El resultado es un poco grande, te pego el resultado cambiando el range a 5:

```
a + p =  q
-a + p =  y
-a - p =  y

l + d =  a
-l + d =  o
-l - d =  a

i + q =  n
-i + q =  n
-i - q =  b

w + i =  m
-w + i =  m
-w - i =  m

m + c =  k
-m + c =  k
-m - c =  k



-----------------------------------------------

[{a: -p + q}]
[{a: d + l}]
[{i: n - q}]
[{i: m - w}]
[{c: k - m}]
```

En tu archivo solo estas resolviendo la ecuación 1, cuando añado las tres ecuaciones al solve lo normal es que te diga que la letra es 0 o que tiene el mismo valor que otra letra:

```
eqs = [
    Eq(sympify(view_expr1.split('=')[0].strip()), sympify(view_expr1.split('=')[1].strip())),  # Crea la ecuación 1
    Eq(sympify(view_expr2.split('=')[0].strip()), sympify(view_expr2.split('=')[1].strip())), # Crea la ecuación 2
    Eq(sympify(view_expr3.split('=')[0].strip()), sympify(view_expr3.split('=')[1].strip()))  # Crea la ecuación 3
]
resultado = solve(eqs)  # Resuelve las ecuaciones
```

Resultado range 5:

```
n + q =  t
-n + q =  t
-n - q =  t

c + n =  t
-c + n =  m
-c - n =  m

e + h =  x
-e + h =  x
-e - h =  x

o + c =  h
-o + c =  i
-o - c =  i

i + x =  r
-i + x =  o
-i - x =  o



-----------------------------------------------

{n: 0, q: 0, t: 0}
{c: t, m: -t, n: 0}
{e: 0, h: 0, x: 0}
{c: 0, h: o, i: -o}
{i: r, o: -r, x: 0}
```

Comment: Está excelente tu respuesta, sin embargo ya había solucionado ese problema por medio de sympy, trataba de usar un método que mezclé para tratar de resolver este tipo de ecuaciones de 3x2, pero me di cuenta de que este método no siempre es aplicable y puede haber situaciones en las que no funcione. Acabo de aplicar otro método y funciona. Pero con los métodos tradicionales, no tengo problema de programarlos. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta